# Comparación de fechas en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Tengo un pequeño problema al comparar dos fechas, una la cual es tomada desde un campo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
     <div class="input-group date fj-date" data-provide="datepicker">
     <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaFactura" ng-model="model_fecha" required>
     <div class="input-group-addon" >
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" ></span>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma espero comparar las fechas:

```
        $scope.CurrentDate = new Date();
        $scope.CurrentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);//Seteo las horas para que el fomato quede igual
        if ($scope.model_fecha != $scope.CurrentDate)
              {
                console.log($scope.model_fecha);
                console.log($scope.CurrentDate);
                alert("La fecha no coincide con la del sistema.")
              }
              else
              {
                if(confirm("¿Estás seguro(a) de realizar este pedido?"))
                {
                  $http.post("mainApp/Create/insertPedidoInsumo.php",
                  {
                    'model_punto':$scope.model_punto,
                    'model_tipofactura':$scope.model_tipofactura,
                    'model_pago':$scope.model_pago,
                    'model_fecha':$scope.model_fecha,
                    'model_producto':$scope.model_producto,
                    'model_cantidad':$scope.model_cantidad

                  }).then(function(datosRealizarPedido)
                  {
                    alert("¡Se ha agregado!");

                  },function errorCallback(datosRealizarPedido)
                  {
                    alert("¡error!")
                  });
                }
              }
```

Pero el problema es que el resultado del Objeto es diferente, cuando en realidad son iguales (Bueno a primera vista, lo es):

model_fecha:

> Date 2017-05-31T05:00:00.000Z

CurrentDate:

> Date 2017-05-31T05:00:00.000Z

Pero, aun asi despues del resultado, sigue ingresando al condicional en donde compara las fechas "alert("La fecha no coincide con la del sistema.")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto si te sirve:

```
$scope.model_fecha.getTime() != $scope.CurrentDate.getTime()
```

Te dejo un ejemplo para probar:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H4Xab5qBcOoPUcsFGdWS?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando. En caso contrario, pregunta todo lo que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió tu solucion! .

Answer (score 5):

Te recomiendo el uso de la librería momentjs https://momentjs.com/

Este pequeño código que he cogido prestado, devuelve 1 si momentA es mayor que momentB, -1 si es menor y 0 si son iguales.

```
 function compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB) {
    var momentA = moment(dateTimeA,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    var momentB = moment(dateTimeB,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    if (momentA > momentB) return 1;
    else if (momentA < momentB) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

alert(compare("10/07/2015", "10/07/2015"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guhokemk/1/